# Does Visual Studio (2022) have a "XAML design debug output" window?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, debugging, visual-studio-2022, output-window

I have two xaml files:

- one (present in solution1) I can see in the design view.
- the other one (present in solution2) I can't see in the design view.

There's nothing wrong with the second xaml: I can see it when I run the application. But I would like to see it in design view (if ever I need to perform a modification, I'll see what I'm doing).

In order to learn, I decided to open the one in solution1 in design view and see in the "Output" window how everything should behave, and based on that, I'd learn what to do.

That failed, because, when opening a xaml file in design view, nothing is added to Visual Studio's "Output" window (nothing in the "Debug" chapter, nothing either in "Build", "Build order" or the other chapters).

For your information, my xaml-related settings look as follows:

[image]

Where can I see what happens in the design view of Visual Studio (2022) while opening a xaml file?

This is how the second xaml looks like, together with the output window (as you see, there is absolutely nothing, so I'm wondering what I should do in order to see something):

[image]

Comment: If possible, could you please offer more information such as the type of those two projects? Are they the same? If not, what are the types?

Comment: And if possible, could you please share the performance screenshots?

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT: both solutions are basic client-server C# applications, where the client sides are C# WPF applications, based on XAML files.

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime I've found another way to solve my problem: my xaml consisted out of `UserControl`s, located within a `Grid`, located within ..., located within a `zoomControl`, and that overall embedding `zoomControl` was messing everything up.

I've found this by replacing all my `UserControl`s by `Label`s, but still the XAML was not shown. Only with the `zoomControl` out of the picture, I started seeing things, I could even see all `UserControl`s.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these settings:

[image]

[image]

Comment: All those things are set, but I don't see anything in my output window.